# Live chat in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Can anyone suggest me the approach of implementing the live chat functionality in my ruby on rails application? Is there any plugin exists to implement this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: i have done it with shooting_star & meteor_strike, one more i know is juggernaut.

Comment: http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/.. i have followed the steps of this blog to get the live chat functionality. But i was not able to achieve the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/).  Unfortunately it requires flash, but it works pretty well otherwise.  You might also want to look at the WebSockets standard, as there is flash emulation for it in browsers that don't support it yet.

Comment: hi Preston.Thanks for your immediate response.What do you mean by flash emulation. Is there any other requirements for this.

Thank you

Comment: Juggernaut uses flash, so there emulation doesn't apply to it.  WebSockets on the other hand are really new, but some browsers support them.  For browsers that don't support it, there is a Flash app that emulates it: http://www.websockets.org/ for more info

Comment: http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/.. i have followed the steps of this blog to get the live chat functionality. But i was not able to achieve the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple (possibly not very efficient) implementation would involve using AJAX to send new messages and receive conversation updates.  The conversation could be a database backed object shared amongst the users involved.  Each user's page would then poll for updates to that object.